# add string to memo box line, then empty string, add new input on next line - delphi 2010 - help!

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

what im trying to do:

input in an edit box, write it to a memo box line on button click, when a 0 or -1 is entered move on to next line of edit box

code:

```
procedure TForm1.btnReadClick(Sender: TObject);

var
c, i, j : integer;
ch2 : Char;
txt1, txt2 : string;

begin
c := StrToInt(edt2.Text);   //input    
ch2 := Converteer(c);       //input gets converted to Char

if memC.Lines.Count = 0 then  //start value when memo box empty
begin
    i := 0;
    j := 0;
    txt1 :='';
    txt2 :='';
end;

if c = 0 then         //text naar memo       
begin
i := i + 1;                   // next line ?!?        these two seem not to work        
txt1 := '';                   // empty string ?!?     these two seem not to work         
txt2 := memT.Lines[j] + ch2;    
end

else if c = -1 then   //same, it appears 'i' is maybe reset everytime button is pressed

begin
    i := i + 1;
    j := j + 1;
    txt1 := '';
    txt2 := '';
   end

else if c >= 0 then   // a t/m z

begin
 txt1 := memC.Lines[i] + IntToStr(c);        
 txt2 := memT.Lines[j] + ch2;
end;


memC.Lines[i] := txt1;         //write string to line  , [i] should specify the wich line    
memT.Lines[j] := txt2;         // same

end.
```

i cant find where/how it goes wrong, it be awesome if someone could give me a hand.

greetz peter

Answer (score 1):

The variables `i`, `j`, `txt1`, `txt2` are uninitialised if the memo box `memC` is not empty. You set them to 0/empty if it is - what are you expecting them to be in other cases? Note that their values won't be preserved across multiple button clicks, because you've declared them as local to this function...

Comment: okay thanks, at start memC is always empty in my case, but i think that making them not local (global?) might solve my problem. ill google how that works, be right back :)

Comment: alright, that pretty much did it. one part isnt working though.

Comment: i have 2 memo boxes, one gets input directly ('i' variabel box) and the other one gets input after convertion. somehow only the 'i' memo isnt working properly now. after moving to the next line it no longer shows input in the 'i' memo. although the other one is working perfectly fine. any ideas?

Comment: weird part is that code for both memo boxes is nearly the same

Comment: It's kind of hard to say without being able to see the code. If this is part of the same problem, then please update the question (including the new code); if it's a separate issue in the same code please ask a new question (and post the link here if you like).

Comment: @peter: You say "i think that making them not local (global?)". Making a variable global in an OOP language is almost never the right answer! You probably want to make the variable a member of the form class.